# Count of items with having common name (different index in the middle as Name)

Tags: javascript, count

I have a record on a list and is displayed on my page. 
they are named like

```
name="detailList[0].category"
name="detailList[1].category"
name="detailList[2].category"
```

how would I be able to count the number of elements having this NAME. "detailList[x].category"
Note: I can't use id . because I am using jsp and it is automatically set to the name when I declared them using logic:iterate.

Comment: `var count = document.querySelectorAll('[name="detailList[x].category"]').length`

Comment: not working dude :(

Comment: Any exceptions?

Comment: I put it on an onClick function of a button (and does a simple alert ) and it does not proceed with the alert. meaning it does not count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var countElements = $('[name^="detailList["]').filter('[name$="].category"]').length;
```

this will give you all elements with names starting with "detailList[" and ending with "].category"
so it will not match name="detailList[2].foo" for example

Comment: I appreciate that you understood my question. that is exactly what I want to happen. But can you please show me more.. I need to do it on javascript
and can you please put it into code that it will be saved in a variable, the count of all element that starts and ends with those tags. 
thank you

Comment: sure see the updated solution, you will need to load jquery on your site for this to work obviousley

Comment: im not really good at that jquery thing. isn't there a pure javascript method for this?

Comment: if you what to use a pure js method see the answer of @Jaromanda-x

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `detailList[x].category` matches all three, i.e. x is any number

```js
var result = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('[name^="detailList["]'), function(item) {
    return item.name.match(/^detailList\[\d+\].category$/);
}).length;

console.log(result, 'matches');
```

```html
<input name="detailList[0].category"/>
<input name="detailList[1].category"/>
<input name="detailList[2].category"/>
<input name="detailList[DoesntMatchThePattern"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('[property=value]'); // All with "property" set to "value" exactly.
```